# How can I make ta.pivothigh / ta.pivotlow, consider only bullish candlesticks / bearish candlesticks respectively?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I need to know how I can add this in the code.

I want `ta.pivothigh()` to consider only bullish candles. and `ta.pivotlow()` to only consider bearish candles, to take this as a `s/r`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Mi script", overlay=true)

leftBars = input(2)
rightBars = input(3)

var float pivothighValue = na
var float pivotlowhValue = na

pivothighValue := ta.pivothigh(leftBars, rightBars)

pivotlowhValue := ta.pivotlow(leftBars, rightBars)

plot(pivothighValue, style=plot.style_stepline_diamond, linewidth=1, color=color.red, offset=-rightBars)
plot(pivotlowhValue, style=plot.style_stepline_diamond, linewidth=1, color=color.red, offset=-rightBars)
```